# Issue with link between documents (xr-hyper) and PDF viewers

Tags: hyperref, pdf, viewers, xr

I am using the package `xr-hyper` and `xr-zref` to generate `hyperlinks` and `references` between different documents. By far the packages work really well and generate all links and refs. The problem is that I just can open these links with `Acrobat Reader`. I am using `macOs Sonoma` and I tried a lot of different PDF viewers: `Skim`, `MuPDF (Homebrew)`, `Evince (Homebrew)`, etc. But as far as I am using, none of them was able to open the link to the other documents.

I checked the link structure and I got this (example):

```
file://full/path/to/pdf.pdf#nameddest=section.1.1
```

As I said, this works perfectly in `Acrobat Reader`, but it does not work in other PDF viewers. So, I have these questions:

1. Has someone here the same issue?
2. Is there any restriction of PDF viewers that are compatible with `xr-hyper` links?

Comment: Well years ago i tested file links and got a similar result (on windows). Often they don't work and absolute pathes are problematic. See  https://github.com/latex3/pdfresources/blob/main/experiments/filelinks/test-filelinks.pdf